# How to retain NaN values using pandas factorize()?

Tags: pandas, nan

I have a Pandas data frame with several columns, with some columns comprising categorical entries. I convert (or, encode) these entries to numerical values using factorize() as follows:

```
for column in df.select_dtypes(['category']):
     df[column] = df[column].factorize(na_sentinel=None)[0]
```

The columns have several NaN entries, so I let na_sentinel=None to retain the NaN entries.  However, the NaN values are not retained (they get converted to numerical entries), which is not what I desire. My Pandas version is 1.3.5.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Factorize converts NaN values by default to -1. The NaN values are retained in this way since the NaN values can be identified by the -1. You would probably want to keep the default which is:

```
na_sentinel =-1
```

see
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html

Comment: Yes, the NaN values are replaced by -1.  However, is there a way to retain it as 'NaN'?  I know -1 could be replaced using 'replace', however is there a way to automatically retain NaN?

Comment: Also, I notice that in some columns NaNs are retained.  While in some others they get replaced by -1.  Strange!